# try block with empty finally block

Tags: java, try-catch

When we have a try block without any code is finally block, the compiler compiles it fine. However, there is no purpose of try here - because we are neither catching a exception nor cleaning up code in finally block.

```
public int updateTable(InputVo sfVo){
    //SqlSession session = ConnFactory.getSqlSession();
    //InputMapper spMapper = session.getMapper(InputMapper .class);
    int updRecs=0;
    try {

        mapper.updateData(sfVo);    

        updRecs=sfVo.getRecsUpdated();
        return updRecs;

    } finally {
        //session.close();
    }
}
```

If thats the case, why does JAVA has not considered a compile time check on this ?

Wouldn't be better if compiler throws error at compile time itself - like "Cannot have a empty finally block"

Comment: You don't need to have code that throws an exception for a `try` block.

Comment: "...JAVA has not considered a compile time check on this" can you expand more on what you mean by this question?

Comment: it is an error to have unnecessary `catch` block, but not `try` or `finally` block. So this could be a warning but I don't see the need to have a compilation error here.

Comment: Empty `if` blocks are not an error, empty methods are not an error, why should an empty `try` block cause the compiler to complain?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why the Java compiler allows this or why Java allows this? The Java compiler allows this because Java allows this, and if the Java compiler were to disallow something that Java allows, then it wouldn't be a *Java* compiler, it would be a compiler for a different language that is kinda-sorta like Java but is not Java. If you are asking why Java allows this, then this question cannot be answered on [so], you will have to ask Patrick Naughton, James Gosling, or whoever else it was who designed Java's exception system. We cannot read their minds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `try-finally` statement without declaring a `catch` statement is legal.

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) :

> 14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally
>
> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing
>   the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally
>   block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
> If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement
>   completes normally.
>
> If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try
>   statement completes abruptly for reason S.

You said :

> we are neither catching a exception nor cleaning up code in finally
>   block.
>   If thats the case, why does JAVA has not considered a compile time
>   check on this ?

What you write in the `finally` statement is of course at the hand of the developer.
Having a empty `finally` statement is useless but it is the same thing that having an empty `if` or `for` statement.
These are helpless but the compiler will not complain about it as it stays valid code in terms of compilation.
However, IDEs could emit warnings about it to point bad smells.

Comment: You beat me to it !

Comment: @ AxelH You would do an answer ? :)

Comment: I was searching for the JLS link ;) I would not have answered better than that !

Comment: @davidxxx, My above code in try block works exact same with out try-finally block. If thats the case, then shouldn't java compiler be more smart enough in upcoming version

Comment: @AlexH We should know by heart the JVM to answer faster :) Thanks to you :)

Comment: @Srikanth A dead code is not a compilation error. Imagine a compiler that tries to be too clever : you have not still finished to write your code and the compiler shout you : "compilation error because empty statement". Besides you can write an empty statement, stop your development task as you need more information to go on. You could so write the code later. During this time, the compilation should fail ??  Imagine the consequences in a project that implies more than one person : you block other persons as a statement code is in progress state. It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: To add an example to davidxxx's comment, just try to implement an interface with 20 methods. If you can't run your test before you have implemented all of those, you are going to have a hard time to debug this class.

Comment: @davidxxx,  I was trying to fix a sonar issue - "Avoid empty finally blocks", so was trying to understand a bit.
I am fixing the issue by removing the try and finally, and keeping the code with out it. should it be ok, or you would suggest a better approach like logging ?

Comment: @Srikanth in the actual code you don't explicitly open any connection or object that should free resources after processing, so I don't see what you could write in your `finally` statement. I don't think you need logging either as you don't try to catch a potential issue that could occur in the block code executed in the `try` statement.  Just removing the `try-finally` seems fine. I think that the original version of the code (that is actually commented) needed a `try--catch-finally` but it is not the case any longer.

Comment: It could be use to log a `Something went wrong`, it would be the same that to have a `catch(Exception e) { log("Something went wrong"); throw e;} but without the reason (so probably not that useful ;) ).

Comment: Thanks @AxelH, and david

Comment: @Srikanth You are welcome :) Personally I find it an interesting question. I upvoted it and I answered despite multiple downvotes. Questions that refer to the language intention are sometimes not very welcome as it is not always easy to understand the intentions of the people that have set the rules of the language.

Answer (score 2):

To add some context, finally is just keyword/label to identify a block statement linked to the `try`. It's like a `goto` that is called in the `try`.

Every block statement can be empty.

```
if(true){}
--
while(true){}
--
public void method(){}
```

even this is valid

```
public void method(){
    {}
}
```

So, we could say that the compiler don't care about the content of those, only the syntax in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you surrounded your exception-throwing code in a `try-catch` or `try-finally` statement, the compiler knows you processed the potential error. What you do with it is up to you, it is authorized to ignore it.

You could argue: "**How is that different than no try at all?**". The difference is that if you don't put it in a `try` clause, the compiler can't know if you did it on purpose or you forgot it.

Basically, catching an exception is mandatory, but processing it isn't.

Comment: Actually, he didn't catch any exception, so a checked exception would need to be defined in the method signature or it will not compile. a `try-finallly` just permit you to execute some code in the finally before that exception stop the method

Comment: @AxelH You can use a `try-finally` construct without any exception thrown in the try, it **will** compile.

Comment: "_The difference is that if you don't put it in a try clause, the compiler can't know if you did it on purpose or you forgot it._", if there is a checked-exception, the compiler will know that you didn't catch it, so will check if you defined the exception in the method signature (throws). If you didn't, it's a compile-time error. So having a `try-finally` or not don't change anything as the method still need to defined the possible exception that will be throwned.

Comment: @AxelH You said yourself that his code doesn't throw an exception. So he doesn't need a catch block.

Comment: When exactly did I said that ? And I have quoted your answer that said there is a difference between having one or not... which is not correct.

Comment: @AxelH You said: "Actually, he didn't catch any exception". And ther **is** a difference between having or not having an exception -- you don't put a catch clause if you don't throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, he didn't put any catch clause there, that doesn't mean there is no exception! And even so, you can add a catch... you can't catch a checked-exception if it is not throwned in the `try` but you can catch a `unchecked` or simply `Exception`/`Throwable`/`Error` as the compiler can't know if there will occurs. But to stay focused, the following don't mean anything : "_The difference is that if you don't put it in a try clause, the compiler can't know if you did it on purpose or you forgot it._" without saying that catching an exception is **not** mandatory